# PowerShell - Header in CSV file and modify a value in a specific column

Tags: powershell, csv, header, arithmetic-expressions

I am newbee in Powershell and i would like to get some answers to my few questions.

That I want to do :
I have a CSV file without Header (about 30-35 columns) and i would like to modify value in the column 20. I would replace this value by (newvalue = this value*5).

My problems :
- it is an obligation to create header to my CSV file to access at the column 20 to modify my value ? (If yes, how can a do that ??)
- How can i modify every line of my CSV file in the colum20 by this :
newvalue = column20.value * 5

Thanks for help

Comment: Dany, good to make your single question more specific, otherwise it looks like your asking to be tutored effectively, which this site does not do.  I suggest to get some help, present a specific coding question, with a coding block of what code you have currently tried and the outcome of that code. Even if you are learning, good to show what you have, and seek help from there.

Comment: Thx Cam_Aust for your words. Actually, i tried some codes but it was so a mess so i put nothing there :)

Comment: OK, and seems you have at least one answer. That is good. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$csvImport = Import-Csv .\listOfUsers.csv -Header "name","samname","fullname","firstName","lastname","description","company","country","city","multi","targetNum"


foreach ($item in $csvImport){
    [int]$item.targetNum= [int]$item.targetNum * 5
}
$csvImport | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | select -Skip 1 | Set-Content .\listOfUsers.csv
```

I chose 11th column but it should work for you for 20th column as well.

Comment: Thx Ketanbhut, I am going to try this, i did not experiment this one :) I can see that it is mandatory to put header names to my lots of column...thanks for your light

Comment: If you wish, you can keep header names anything if they are not useful to you in future. Like header1, header2....header20, you are going to remove it in last line anyways.

Comment: Ketanbhut, I tried your code but I had 2 problems. I could resolve one: I put a Get-content before the Import-csv (for encoding in unicode). But I do not know what to do about my data comming out. I would like something like this : lilou;125;eric;45 but here i have "lilou,"125","eric","45" ...Why???

Comment: it is ok I get it !!! My piece of code : $csvImport | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';' | % {$_ -replace '"',''}| select -Skip 1 | Set-Content .\listOfUsers.csv

Answer (score 0):

For demonstration purposes the following script

- first generates a file `noHeader.csv` with random number of columns
  (10..15), rows(5..10) and content.
- The second part reads in the first line,   splits it at ',' comma to
  get the column count and   builds a pseudo Header `H1,H2,...Hx` where
  x is the column count.
- It `import-csv` the file and multipies H10 by 5 (casting to double)

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\05\29\SO_50581599.ps1
$CsvFile = '.\NoHeader.csv'
$NewFile  = '.\WithHeader.csv'
## ======================================================================
## Generate Csv without Header with random no of cols,rows,content
$cols= get-random -min 10 -max 15
$rows= get-random -min 5  -max 10

$Data = ForEach ($Row in (1..$Rows)){
    (1..$Cols | ForEach-Object{Get-Random -min 100 -max 1000} ) -join ','
}
$Data | Out-File $CsvFile
"Generated {0} with {1} columns and {2} rows" -f $CsvFile,$cols,$rows
GC $CsvFile
"=" * 70
## ======================================================================
## evaluate number of columns in file $CsvFile
$ColCnt = ((Get-Content $CsvFile | Select -First 1) -split ',').Count
"File {0} has {1} columns" -f $CsvFile,$ColCnt

## generate Header H1..Hx
$Header = (1..$ColCnt | ForEach-Object{"H{0}" -f $_})

$NewCsv = ForEach($row in (Import-Csv $CsvFile -Header $Header)){
    [double]$row.H10 *= 5
    $row
}
$NewCsv |ft * -auto
$NewCsv | Export-csv $NewFile -NoType
```

---

```
Generated .\NoHeader.csv with 11 columns and 8 rows
591,864,196,281,599,216,152,236,621,311,934
942,222,522,590,649,788,421,665,493,116,282
359,984,645,276,297,320,632,934,296,197,750
746,486,375,756,462,286,977,834,765,828,907
156,899,258,941,222,517,170,301,739,501,414
395,891,182,224,430,773,115,645,114,919,401
743,475,335,650,222,899,690,442,525,695,539
861,341,114,498,550,824,635,407,235,285,631
======================================================================
File .\NoHeader.csv has 11 columns

H1  H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7  H8  H9   H10 H11
--  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --   --- ---
591 864 196 281 599 216 152 236 621 1555 934
942 222 522 590 649 788 421 665 493  580 282
359 984 645 276 297 320 632 934 296  985 750
746 486 375 756 462 286 977 834 765 4140 907
156 899 258 941 222 517 170 301 739 2505 414
395 891 182 224 430 773 115 645 114 4595 401
743 475 335 650 222 899 690 442 525 3475 539
861 341 114 498 550 824 635 407 235 1425 631
```

Comment: Thx LotPings, I was looking for this kind of code as I got more than 30 column.

Comment: The code works with any number of cols, I just reduced cols to fit the output in without scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i get it as i wish :

## Use Unicode because of accent characters

```
    $FicCSV = "C:\Temp\mycsvfile.csv"
Get-Content $FicCSV | Out-File "C:\Temp\mycsvfile_Unicode.csv" -Encoding Unicode
$csvImport = Import-Csv -path "C:\Temp\mycsvfile_Unicode.csv" -Header "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L1","L2","M","N","O","P","Q","R1","R2","R3","R4","R5","R6","R7","R8","R9","S","T","U","V","W" -delimiter ';'
```

## Decimal to do my maths operation

```
    foreach ($item in $csvImport){
    [decimal]$item.P= [decimal]$item.P * 5
}
```

## my file must be with records like this : lea;john;katy;10.2;george;..

```
$csvImport | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';' | % {$_.replace('"','').replace(',','.')}| select -Skip 1 | Set-Content "C:\Temp\mycsvfile_back.csv"
```

Thanks for EveryOne who helped me to succeed :)